Start my Fish shell always from home, rather than the previous location?
I use the Fish shell, using the config from this dotfiles repository: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/dotfiles/tree/main/fish.
The problem is that whenever I open a new tab in my terminal, that it starts off from the previous path, instead of from my user's home folder. How can I change this behavior so that every terminal always opens from ~?
The weird thing is that I've been using these dotfiles for forever and I never had this problem until I formatted my computer and set it up from scratch. No idea why now it behaves like this, but I really don't like it.

The solution is to update your config.fish file
# all your actual command

# Start in home directory
cd ~

By adding the cd ~ at the end of your config file, it'll be excecuted everytime you open a new fish instance as the last command.
You can change the ~ with any path where you want to start from but the ~ is for home.
It's similar to a .bashrc or a .zshrc only the name change

Ah, right. Simple enough :) Any idea why this didn't happen until I reinstalled my computer about 3 weeks ago?

The home path is the default path on almost all terminal. So it's normal if you didn't have it before. But I have no idea of how you reinstalled your computer and the issue might be coming from the way you did

@KevinRenskers Yes it's simple but you can do a lot in those configuration files, things like alias, calling whole script or updating all your package every certain times. Search for .bashrc, .zshrc and config.fish examples it's fun and offer a lot of customization options

Sadly the cd ~ isn't really a good fix, because now when I start a terminal from within VSCode it also starts in the home folder instead of the project folder. I'm really not sure why this is all behaving so differently now :/

So, turns out it was a "feature" of Warp, a new terminal I was trying out. Not a problem with Fish.

I found a way to bypass vsCode going to home.
Try adding a if before the cd with this condition "$TERM_PROGRAM" != "vscode"
